# Работа скрипта python в спящем режиме компьютера

Tags: python, sleep

Возможно ли продолжать исполнение python скрипта при спящем режиме компьютера? И как это сделать?

**P.S.** Если что, это нужно для бота ВК на личное пользование

**P.P.S.** pythonanywhere мне не подходит, т.к. на нем нельзя делать GET запросы к сайтам вне белого списка

Comment: Нет, невозможно.

Comment: @вася https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222304/python-script-stops-running-when-screen-turns-off  ???

Comment: `pythonanywhere мне не подходит, т.к. на нем нельзя делать GET запросы к сайтам вне белого списка` — heroku?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica <offtopic>Вы и сами можете [посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/394322/вася?tab=reputation)</offtopic>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У компьютера есть ряд разных режимов энергосбережения, каждый имеет свои особенности:

**Отключение монитора** не является ни ждущим, ни спящим режимом, это просто отключение устройства отображения. Процессор при этом работает и продолжает выполнять программы, в том числе и написанные на питоне. Никаких специальных действий от программиста не требуется.

**При ждущем режиме** процессор компьютера остановлен, работает только  контроллер RAM для того, чтобы ее содержимое не исчезло.

Нет, остановленный процессор не будет исполнять программу, даже если она написана на питоне.

**В режиме гибернации** компьютер полностью выключается. Полностью выключенный компьютер тоже ничего делать не может.

Однако, нужно понимать, что домашний компьютер не рассчитан на круглосуточную работу в качестве сервера. Как минимум, вентиляторы от такой эксплуатации износятся и начнут шуметь.

Comment: У меня так уже работал блин. По совету одного опытного разраба "у нас они тут круглосуточно работают". В результате накрылась (судя по всему) видеокарта (и так барахлящая — комп что запустится делал несколько ребутов сам). Ну все комп не может стартануть (а там исходники некоторых моих личных проектов). Так что дельный совет!

Answer (score 3):

Не получится. Для этого существуют vps. А из бесплатных - pythonanywhere, heroku.

Comment: Насчёт heroku... Я слышал что его довольно сложно настраивать, но меня больше интересует вопрос, возможно ли оттуда делать GET запросы к любым сайтам?

Comment: Ну во-первых, heroku, не так уж и сложно настраивать - добавить requirements.txt, Procfile и runtime.txt к проекту, и считай, все готово. А во-вторых, на счет запросов не знаю, но скорее всего можно

Comment: Вот сначала нужно узнать про запросы, и если всё ок, то я попробую heroku

Comment: Ок. Сейчас создам тестовое приложение и проверю

Comment: Попробуй плиз на tv.mail.ru

Comment: @МихаилМуратов `Попробуй плиз на tv.mail.ru` — what?

Comment: Тема такая, залил я туда обычного echo-бота. Запросы работают, но вылезает ошибка R10 (Boot timeout). Бот там проработает пару секунд или минут и все, а потом падает. Решается это использованием вебхуков, но это уже муторно все. Так что лучше купи vps, и всех своих ботов (сколько бы у тебя их не было) там запускай

Comment: Вот вот, а я сразу говорил, что муторно на heroku делать. Но спасибо, что спас меня от ненужной возни

Comment: @МихаилМуратов нашел я как в heroku бесплатно бота запилить, чтоб все работало. Надо будет напиши

Comment: @lleballex да, всё ещё надо, подскажи пожалуйста

Comment: Ты ведь никогда не пользовался Heroku? Тебе надо будет скачать Heroku CLI, зарегистрироваться на сайте и создать новое приложение. А что дальше, скажу потом

Comment: Я нашел решение проще, но спасибо. Чекай какой я ответ добавил

Answer (score 0):

Короче, есть такая классная (а главное бесплатная) вещь, как Google Cloud. Благодаря этому [туториалу](https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?hl=ru&tutorial=python_gae_quickstart) у меня получилось настроить бота VK, и теперь всё работает отлично!

Upd: всё не так хорошо, через некоторое время бот просто отключился ×_×